# What you see as the main results of applying Category Theory to general topology?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

What you see as the main results of applying Category Theory to general topology?

Comment: IMO there are no such results. Sometimes category theory is used as a guide to generalisations etc. There are some interesting topological "flavour" categories, but that's not a result applied to the field, just a view on a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen a result in general topology that comes from applying a result from category theory at all. Set theory is applied all the time and is closely linked. Category theory seems more remote. Yes, we can see constructions (products, quotients etc.) as special cases of limits in appropriate categories (initial and final topologies etc.) but topologists have been showing results on products without using that they are categorical limits. Links to other structures (like Stone duality) are nice to have and guide research sometimes, but I haven't seen that as applications of category theory. No significant topological facts have been learnt from that AFAIK.

Maybe others have different ideas.

Comment: I will not downgrade, but I strongly disagree with this answer (at least if we consider modern algebraic topology, which is essentially built out from category theoretical results and language)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud The question is about **general** topology which excludes algebraic topology, which uses category theory as its primary tool.

Answer (score 3):

The Quillen equivalence between simplicial sets and (compactly generated, Hausdorff) spaces shows that the (weak) homotopy theory of topological spaces and the one of simplicial sets, which is much more combinatorial and less prone to pathological cases. Very often in modern algebraic topology one uses simplicial sets and topological spaces interchangeably.

This is the starting point for a lot of ideas, leading to modern $\infty$-categories (via the Joyal model structure on simplicial sets).

Note that this is a result in algebraic topology rather than point-set topology, but I think it is still in scope of your original question.